# Java Stream Collectors.toMap- How to convert to a different concurrent Map

Tags: java-8, concurrenthashmap, concurrentmodification, collectors

I am working on java 8 streams and its `collectors.collect` functionality.
I have converted a list stream into a `Map<String, String >` as follows:

```
Map<Integer, String> mb = persons.stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                            p -> p.age, 
                                            p -> p.name, 
                                            (name1, name2) -> name1+";"+name2));
```

Is there any way I can convert this into a `concurrentHashMap`?
As of previous versions of java i can do it by `Collections.synchronizedMap`. 
Any way to do it through streams and lambda?